# Is it safe to do a git pull from master to my local repo after creating a new branch on which I need to see the latest changes too?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull

I would like to have the latest updates from the remote repo on my local one. I usually do git pull while being on the master branch and then create a new branch. I have now created a new branch (did not add/change anything in the local code) but skipped the git pull on master before this. If I do a git pull, will the latest remote modifications be reflected on my new local branch and local master, or should I delete it and recreate it after git pull?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What git will do depends on the *exact* command you issue, and also on your git configuration.

The first thing to understand about `pull` is, it updates the current branch.  If you check out `master` and then `pull`, the changes you pull will be incorporated into `master` (but not your branch).  If you check out your branch and then `pull`, the changes will be incorporated into your branch (but not `master`).  This, of course, is the point of branching - changes to one branch don't automatically affect the other.  If you want to affect both, you can (see below for more on that).

Also, you can tell git what changes to incorporate into the current branch, or if you don't specify then it will look for a configured default corresponding to the current branch.  (Some people seem to think this default behavior is all `pull` does, and that can get them into trouble.)  So if you want to integrate the remote `master`'s changes into your branch, you can do

```
git checkout my_branch
git pull origin master
```

I typically don't recommend this usage.  It's basically a shorthand for

```
git checkout my_branch
git fetch 
git merge origin/master
```

which is a little more explicit (so less dependent on configuration details, etc.).  I use `pull` quite a bit, but only for its default behavior in repos whose configuration/branch setup is "typical".

Now, if you want the `origin/master` changes reflected in multiple branches, then you have to perform multiple merge (and/or rebase) operations; and a given `pull` only does one.  So typically you'd first get the changes into your local `master`

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

(or, depending on configuration, maybe you'd need `git pull origin` or even `git pull origin master`).  Then you'd incorporate them into the branch by either

```
git checkout my_branch
git merge master
```

or

```
git rebase master my_branch
```

Comment: +1 and removing my answer because this one is more complete and frankly a much better answer. Only thing I'll add is it is optional to round-trip the changes through a local master branch. Both `master` and `origin/master` will resolve to the same commit of your local master is up to date, so any of the commands that use `master` can be executed using `origin/master` and you'll get the same result. I've even gotten into the habit of not keeping a local copy of master at all because it's just one more thing I've got to remember to keep up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Git will try to merge the remote master to your lokal new branch. Since you have no changes you will just get the current remote master to your branch.